# z-index of navigation bar in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drag, navigationbar, navigator

I have tinder like cards that can be swiped left and right out of screen, 
but they render below the navigation bar, is there anyway to re-order the index here? 
My code is setup quite standard, so by logic the bar would always be on top - i think? cant think of anyway around it

```
renderScene(route, nav) {
    const {globalNav} = nav.props;
    switch (route.name) {
        case 'settings' :
            return <Settings />;

        case 'feed' :
            return <Feed />;

        case 'matches' :
            return <Matches />;
    }
}

render() {
    const {globalNav} = this.props;
    return (
        <Navigator
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
            navigationBar={ <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBar} />}
        />
    );
}
```

[see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVsEX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The zIndex layout property worked for me!

From [Layout Props Description](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html)

> zIndex controls which components display on top of others. Normally,
>   you don't use zIndex. Components render according to their order in
>   the document tree, so later components draw over earlier ones. zIndex
>   may be useful if you have animations or custom modal interfaces where
>   you don't want this behavior.
>
> It works like the CSS z-index property - components with a larger
>   zIndex will render on top. Think of the z-direction like it's pointing
>   from the phone into your eyeball. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for more
>   details.